# while sending email from asp.net application css not applied to email format in public domain like gmail

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am sending email from my asp.net application to users in gmail account, css not appliying in email format. However it is coming properly when i send same email in outlook. I have also tried by applying css in head tag but still it resulted the same.

Please provide suitable way to make my mail format look good when i see it in gmail account.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a fundamental problem in email that there is no consistency in the rendering platform of email clients. Your recipient could as easily be using a client that renders plain text as one that has a reasonably capable html engine or - as in the case of google mail - something in between.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify css stylesheet inside the mailbody or apply inline style

Comment: i tried by specifying stylesheet inside the mailbody as well.. but then also there is still some issue....

Comment: can u post the exact issues u r getting?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the `message.IsBodyHtml = true` ?

Comment: yes it is specified..... all other things are getting only css is not coming in gmail

Comment: check out this link: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=1caa65114e0d39d1&hl=en  apparently others have an issue with it as well.

Comment: hey thanks for information..... hope you may find some solution for this issue....

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline css rules like below

```
<a style='color:#000' href='#'>example</a>
```

Also I've noticed that gmail is applying own css rules to mail body so you must use inline to override this styles.